# Linq Query is causing error when trying to retrieve from database

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried the below query to get a list from a database using linq but get the following error

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I'm not sure why the error is being caused.

```
 List<a> a = await (from p in new db_Context().Items
                    where p.sub_Var.Name.Equals((sender as Button).Text)
                    orderby p.Name
                    select p).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: make sure your sender actually is a Button Object every time this function gets called other than this I dont see where a null reference might comw from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name = (sender as Button).Text;

List<a> a = await (from p in new db_Context().Items
                    where p.sub_Var.Name == name 
                    orderby p.Name
                    select p).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

use **==** instead of `Equals`

```
 List<a> a = await (from p in new db_Context().Items
                    where p.sub_Var.Name == ((sender as Button).Text)
                    orderby p.Name
                    select p).ToListAsync();
```

**EDIT**

if you are getting null, set the button text to a variable and check ,

```
string buttonname = (sender as Button).Text;


List<a> a = await (from p in new db_Context().Items
                        where p.sub_Var.Name == buttonname 
                        orderby p.Name
                        select p).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I'm now getting, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. Any ideas and nothing appears to be null

Comment: you need another ( , check the updated answer

Comment: did it work  for you

Comment: Hi the answer was to set it to a variable first, thanks for the help